# Why does nohup not working in python script in os.system?

Tags: python, nohup, os.system

I treid to use nohup in python on cluster but failed. My code is here below:

```
import os

path = "/ldfssz1/SP_MSI/USER/"
os.system("nohup sh "+ path + "myjobs.sh &")
```

Cluster only returns this:

```
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'
```

There were no pid returns and job command returns nothing. Can anyone gives me some idea what's going on here? Thank you very much!

Comment: Guessing, you might need to escape the &

Comment: Why would you ever use `nohup` in this circumstance? It doesn't do anything useful at all.

Comment: ...to expand on that, `nohup` does exactly two things: (1) it redirects any of stdin, stdout and stderr that would otherwise be going to a TTY; and (2) it turns off propagation of HUP signals (which are only TURNED ON in the first place for interactive shells, and `os.system()` creates noninteractive ones exclusively).

Comment: So, `sh myjobs.sh </dev/null >nohup.out 2>nohup.out &` does **exactly** the same thing, without `nohup` involved. But even then, that's a bunch of needless complexity, because there's no reason to involve an extra shell either.

Comment: ("no pid returns" is normal; printing the PID to the TTY is another thing that's only done by _interactive_ shells).

Comment: @moinudin, no, escaping the `&` is absolutely not correct. That would make the exact string `&` be passed as an argument to `myjobs.sh`.